# How do I put text/headings over an image?

Tags: html, css, class

How would I put headings in the center of each of these images? For example over the first one "Music" in the center of the image

```
             <div class="row">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/music_cover.png"/>
             </div>
             <div class="item">
                <img src="images/event_cover.png"/>
             </div>
             <div class="item">
                <img src="images/lights_cover.png"/>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: are your headings multi-line, or "long" (ie wider than the typical width of your `<img />` elements) ?

Answer (score 0):

The below is the CSS code:

```
    /* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/* Bottom left text */
.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

/* Top left text */
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

/* Top right text */
.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

/* Bottom right text */
.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The below is the HTML code.

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
 <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
 <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
 <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
 <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
 <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

I hope this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I would imagine. Create a container that contains both your image and an absolute div to contain the text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.item {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>

</head>

<div class="item">
  <img src="images/music_cover.png" style="width:100%;"/>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you introduced these headings into your HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item">
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <img src="images/music_cover.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <img src="images/event_cover.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <img src="images/lights_cover.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can achieve a quick centered heading result, over your images, by introducing the follow css:

```
.item {
    position:relative;
}

.item h2 {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    line-height:1;
    margin-top:-0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the images backgrounds, use the different properties for position, attachment, size, etc. to get what you need

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Or a more reliable and scalable approach: put the image into an SVG via a tag (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) and add text to the SVG